# Passcode type scanning and population with Watir-webdriver and Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have a username/password/passcode login screen for a webapp i am automating, here is the problem i have and i cannot figure out the best practise to do this.

the login page has username,password and a passcode of 6 digits this are input fields similar to a bank verification screen like enter digits 1 4 5 from passcode, i want to be able to probe the passcode for to find out what digits it requires and then pass though the correct ones accordingly.

here is an example of field enabled

```
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin" maxlength="1" placeholder="1">
```

and here is an example of a field disabled

```
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin6" maxlength="1" placeholder="6" disabled="disabled">
```

any ideas on hows best to handle this

thanks

Comment: How does a user know which digits to enter? Is there some label or text that tells them?

Comment: Hi Again Justin ;), The user has 6 input fields single digit only with placeholder text, the user will have there own 6 digit code, so it will have say XOOXXX as a config, where OO is digit 2 and 3 would need to be entered from your passcode, all passcodes at the moment are 123456 and with XOOXXX i would need to enter 2 into 2nd input box and 3 into 3rd input box, hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the 6 input fields, when the 2nd and 3rd digits are required, look like:

```
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin" maxlength="1" placeholder="1" disabled="disabled">
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin2" maxlength="1" placeholder="2">
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin3" maxlength="1" placeholder="3">
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin4" maxlength="1" placeholder="4" disabled="disabled">
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin5" maxlength="1" placeholder="5" disabled="disabled">
<input class="input-block-level" type="text" data-validate-msg="enter pin " data-validate="true" data-bind="events: { keypress: passcode, keyup: passcode1 }, value: pin6" maxlength="1" placeholder="6" disabled="disabled">
```

Given that you know which passcode digits are required, ie XOOXXX, you could directly access and input those fields by their placeholder attribute:

```
passcode = '123456'
browser.text_field(data_validate_msg: "enter pin ", placeholder: "2").set(passcode[1])
browser.text_field(data_validate_msg: "enter pin ", placeholder: "3").set(passcode[2])
```

Note that in the above code the placeholder attribute is assumed to be 1-based index, where as getting values from the passcode string is 0-based.

If the required passcode digits can change, you could iterate through each field and only input the enabled fields:

```
passcode = '123456'
pins = browser.text_fields(data_validate_msg: "enter pin ")
pins.each do |pin|
  next if pin.disabled?

  passcode_digit = passcode[pin.placeholder.to_i - 1]
  pin.set(passcode_digit)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, i will give a go now, you are correct in that the required digits will change with every page load essentially.

Comment: it would appear they removed the placeholder text in the latest release, so i need another way of finding each pin box via another ID, hmmm these crazy coders with their crazy deployments ;)

Comment: Are the 6 pincode fields the only text fields where the data-validate-msg is "enter pin " - ie if you do `pins.length` is the answer 6? If so, you could just assume the digit based on its position.